# Use Ruby Sinatra erb template to access jQuery Mobile (jqm) multipage html

Tags: javascript, ruby, jquery-mobile, sinatra, erb

I have a standard jQuery-Mobile multipage HTML file that I need to access from my Sinatra application with the ERB templates.  I don't see how to access a bookmark or anchor within the file.

My code is simple:

```
get '/login' do
  erb :'admin.html#login_page'
end
```

But, what I get is:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - .../views/admin.html#login_page.erb:
```

The file that I am trying to access is

> admin.html.erb

with bookmark of login_page.

The portion of the HTML template I am trying to access is as follows, though other pages are included.

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="login_page">
  <%= partial :'main-header.html', locals: {page: 'Management Console Login'} %>
  <div class="ui-content">
    <a href="#login" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Admin
      Login</a>
    <div data-role="popup" data-history="false" id="login" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form action='/login_process' method='post' data-ajax='false'>
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
          <h3>Administrative Login</h3>
          <label for="logon" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Logon:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="logon" placeholder="Logon">
          <label for="password" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" id="loginButton" data-transition="flip" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= partial :'frontend/footer.html' %>
  <script type='application/javascript' src='assets/login_modal.js'></script>
</div>
```

I'd simply render it but I need the Ruby translator.  Any idea how to make this work or of a better way to do it?  Thanks...

Comment: What does the template look? Are you using a layout file or is a standalone template?

Comment: @maxpleaner I added the template.  The question is the method of using the erb template command in a format that provides the capability of referencing a bookmakr/anchor, however.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not possible if you do not modify this method https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L784-L799 at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it basically working with a twist, but still had problems with other code so I am not using it.  I converted the anchor to a local variable and then referenced that it the HTML JavaScript to go to that anchor.

In Sinatra:

```
erb :'admin.html', :locals => {:anchor => "#login_page"}
```

In the page:

```
let body = $("body");
let anchor = <%= "\'#{anchor}\'" %>;
body.on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (event, ui) {
    body.pagecontainer("change", anchor);
});
```

This worked.  The issue I had was that I had to make dynamic changes on one page, based on beforeshow, that I could not get to work.

But, I did solve the question.